# Handler Periodic Delay Android

Tags: java, android, mobile-application

I want to run images in a loop inside a listview . I have Tried using handler but 
 it does not work like i want it to.

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
     Glide.with(context).load(images[position]).into(viewHolder.imageView);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }

    }, 500);


    final Handler handler2 = new Handler();
    handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){           

Glide.with(context).load(secondimages[position]).into(viewHolder.imageView);
            handler2.postDelayed(this, 2000);
        }

    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem?

Comment: I need a handler to run two different array images periodically in a single listview using a single handler........